# mvc3 dropdownlist of operators

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

What is the best way to create the same dropdownlist in mvc3??
as you can see in this link 
[Html JS example](http://jsfiddle.net/miko5054/Qq4wd/)

I tried to do it like this

model:

```
   public enum oporetor
    {

        greater_then = '>',
         less_than  = '<',
         equal = '='



    }

    public oporetor getOp { get; set; }
}
```

view model:

```
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.getOp, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Fnx.Esb.ServiceMonitor.ViewModel.AdvanceSearchModel.oporetor))))
```

view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.AdvanceSearchModel)
```

I got a basic dropdownlist with greater_then, less_than,equal. How can I display a <,>,= in the dropdownlist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.getOp,
    ((Fnx.Esb.ServiceMonitor.ViewModel.AdvanceSearchModel.oporetor[])Enum.GetValues(
        typeof(Fnx.Esb.ServiceMonitor.ViewModel.AdvanceSearchModel.oporetor)
    )).Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = x.ToString(),
        Text = ((char)x).ToString()
    })
)
```

or a better approach would be to prepare this data at your view model directly:

```
public enum Operator
{
    greater_then = '>',
    less_than = '<',
    equal = '='
}

public class AdvanceSearchModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Operators 
    {
        get
        {
            return ((Operator[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Operator)))
                .Select(x => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = x.ToString(),
                    Text = ((char)x).ToString()
                });
        }
    }

    public Operator GetOp { get; set; }
}
```

and then inside the view simply:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GetOp, Model.Operators)
```